# How to save these images in Gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I am trying to save this image in my gallery but when i click on save on that images is saving which i picked from gallery not frame, i want to save both image as they are appearing. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Please share your code!!

Comment: Please Check this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G9VK0X3Kga4caEyuABfNsKEtjVwKjnIV/view

Answer (score 0):

**the gallery don't displaying files from external storage.**

the gallery displays images stored on the media store provider.

you can read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore).

**you can use this method to store image file on media store provider:**

```
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: i want to save that images into sd card. there are two images in layout first is frame and second is image which i picked from my gallery and i want to save that both images as its is in my gallery.